# Is it possible to make a field of a record private? or to make a member of record private?

Tags: f#

I want to stick with `record`, and don't want to go back to `object`. So I am wondering if it is possible to make a `field` of a `record private`? or to make a `private member` of `record`.  what about other `concrete types` such as `discriminated union`?

Or, does this requirement violate the language spec?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nope, it's not possible for single fields to be private: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184

However, you can make all fields private and expose selected fields through properties. Note that you will need a Create-function in order to create an instance of the records, since its' fields are private:

```
type MyRec = 
    private
        { a : int
          b : int }
    member x.A = x.a
    member private x.Both = x.a + x.b  // Members can be private
    static member CreateMyRec(a, b) = { a = a; b = b }
```

Members can be private though, as in the case of the `MyRec.Both` property above.

Edit: The above makes the fields **private to the module** that MyRec is defined in, not private to MyRec. See Daniel's answer to [Weird accessibility scopes when F# record's fields are declared private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461734/weird-accessibility-scopes-when-f-records-fields-are-declared-private/14462045).

Comment: I've never used it, but it seems OK to me. Records give you structural comparison 'for free', so I can see legitimate uses for it.

Comment: It seems weird to me that we are able to put private in front of {}, the msdn doesn't state this usage (and i cannot find in google)

Comment: Yes, it is quite weird and not documented in MS language reference. I stumbled across it by accident, when i saw the error message `Accessibility modifiers are not permitted on record fields. Use 'type R = internal ...' or 'type R = private ...' to give an accessibility to the whole representation.`

Comment: I don't know about MSDN, but it's in the spec. See the table in [this section](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc321997217).

Comment: Answer edited, added information from Daniel's answer to a related question from me.

Comment: of course you could encapsulate the ones you want private in a smaller record, where those properties/fields are private, so that the rest of your properties and the higher record level doesn't require a create function or all the props to be private.

Answer (score 13):

The problem with this requirement is that the language features of record require the properties to be public. For example if you have a record `r` of type `R` with properties `Name` and `Age` and write
`{ r with Age = 20 }`, the compiler turns that into `new R(r.Name, 20)`.

The idea is that `with` copies all properties (excluding the one you want to change) and so it needs to be able to access them. For this, the compiler could actually generate methods for every possible `with` use, but that could generate *a lot* of methods.

What are your reasons for prefering records? They have two nice features - the `with` keyword (which you lose with `private` members anyway) and structural equality (two instances are the same when they have the same values). Aside from that, classes seem to be easier to use, if you want to hide some fields.

Here is a simple example (which does not implement strucural equality):

```
type R(name:string, age:int) = 
  member x.Name = name
  member x.WithAge(newAge) = R(name, newAge)
```

Using records with `private` fields seems fine - although it may make more sense to use public fields within an implementation file and an [F# signature file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233196.aspx) that hides the fields for all external users. This way, you can use features like `with` in the implementation, but still hide the type.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. MSDN says:

> Record fields differ from classes in that they are **automatically
>   exposed as properties**, and they are used in the creation and copying
>   of records. Record construction also differs from class construction.
>   In a record type, you cannot define a constructor.

"Automatically exposed" is a key to answer your question. Is three any reason why you don't want to create a new type?