# Weird accessibility scopes when F# record's fields are declared private

Tags: f#

I just noticed a rather counter intuitive behaviour when the field part of an F# record is declared private. (This is related to [Is it possible to make a field of a record private? or to make a member of record private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389308/is-it-possible-to-make-a-field-of-a-record-private-or-to-make-a-member-of-recor/12389894#12389894))

In this example...

```
type MyRec = 
    private  // Fields declared private, or at least I thought so.
        { a : int
          b : int }
    member x.A = x.a
    member private x.Both = x.a + x.b
    static member CreateMyRec(a, b) = { a = a; b = b }

let foo = MyRec.CreateMyRec(1,2)
let bar = foo.a     // No error. Huh?
let baz = foo.Both  // Error: not accessible.
```

...the private member `Both` is inaccessible outside the type declaration scope, as is expected. However, the field `a` is accessible.

If you put MyRec in a module, the fields become private to that module. That's how you'd expect a top level declaration in the module to behave, but I expected that anything declared private within a type, would be private to that type, not to its enclosing module.

Is this behaviour actually weird, or am I missing something in my reasoning here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is an under-documented feature. But, section 10.5 of the spec, [Accessibility Annotations](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818992), states:

> private on a type, module, or type representation in a module means “private to the module.”

"type representation" being the part relevant to record fields.

Comment: That's a subtle one. Would never have noticed it without your answer.