# Multiple DataMemberAttribute

Tags: f#, datacontract

**Subject**

For the errors, the api is returning two kinds of results, one has the field `error` and for some `error_code`, and an api can return both kinds based on parameters so can't really branch there.

[Deserialize datamember multiple names (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366523/deserialize-datamember-multiple-names)

**JSON 1**

```
{
    "error_code": "234",
    "message": "Api Key is required"
}
```

**JSON 2**

```
{
    "code": "NotFound",
    "message": "Could not find the resource"
}
```

**Code**

```
[<DataContract>]
type Error = {
    [<field: DataMemberAttribute(Name="code",Name="error_code")>]
    code: string
    [<field: DataMemberAttribute(Name="message")>]
    message: string
}
```

**Error**

> A named argument has been assigned more than one value

**Expected Solution**

If same Error type can handle both types of JSON output.

**Edit** based on the given answer.

```
[<DataContract>]
type Error = {
    [<field: DataMemberAttribute(Name="code")>]
    code: string

    [<field: DataMemberAttribute(Name="error_code")>]
    error_code: string

    [<field: DataMemberAttribute(Name="message")>]
    Message: string
} 
with member this.Code : string =
        if not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.code)) then this.code
        else if not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.error_code)) then this.error_code
        else ""
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: is it possible to have a data member attribute for multiple json fields,

Comment: that can store either code or error_code in one field

Comment: Answer: no, it's not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is directly possible with F# record types, but depending on the deserializer behavior, you may be able to something like this:

```
[<DataContract>]
type Error = {
    [<field: DataMemberAttribute(Name="error_code")>]
    numericCode: string
    [<field: DataMemberAttribute(Name="code")>]
    textCode: string
    [<field: DataMemberAttribute(Name="message")>]
    message: string
}
    with member this.code =
        if not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.numericCode)) then Some this.numericCode
        else if not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textCode)) then Some this.textCode
        else None
```

This way you still have to explicitly handle the different cases in your type, but it allows you to just call `error.code` from your code and not worry about the two separate fields.

Depending on which deserializer library you use, you may be able to play around with access modifiers to hide the two fields (but that may be impractical with records) or make their types `Option<string>` so that the type consumers know they should handle missing values.

---

This is also what FSharp.Data's [JsonProvider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html) does if you specify multiple examples with different fields: it merges them together to create a single type able to represent all the examples, with optional fields for values not present in all the examples. Then it's up to you to write helper functions or type extensions for application specific mapping.

Comment: it's giving warnings `then Some numericCode`

Comment: please check my edit, do you see any problem with it?

Comment: It should work if either value is absent, `DataMemberAttribute` has `IsRequired` property, which is false by default. In that case, the deserializer should just leave missing field initialized to null. The watning is probably missing access through `this`, I edited it in later - I'll edit the answer to add it. Your edit looks fine, if it does what we expect it to do :)

Comment: great. **play around with access modifiers to hide the two fields**, can you help with the code, i'm not familiar with that syntax, yes I want to hide those `numericCode` and `textCode`, i'm using `DataContractJsonSerializer`

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking about making the fields private or something, but looks like that's not possible with records either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389308/is-it-possible-to-make-a-field-of-a-record-private-or-to-make-a-member-of-recor

Comment: not possible? but in the answer the solution was there on how to create a private field, what's your reservation?

Comment: True, but essentially by making the whole record private and exposing only the public fields explicitly as new members. If that works for you, it's definitely one way to do it, but it's something different than I had in mind when initially mentioning it. It disallows you from using the record creation syntax for example, and may be a lot of fields for larger types. But is probably fine if the two/three fields are the complete use case for you.

Comment: so if I make my whole record private, will this json marshaling work using `[<field: DataMemberAttribute(Name="code")>]` for private fields while considering the complexity we have?

Comment: That depends on the deserializer if it can find the fields e.g. by using reflection - try it out and see. But for C# classes I think most of them (* of those who use DataMember attributes) work on private fields and properties with private setters, so I'd expect it to work here too.